# How set mpv2 for MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, java-package

I'm trying to run [these](http://www.ux.uis.no/~karlsk/dle/) from [Karl Skretting](http://www.ux.uis.no/~karlsk) for dictionary learning in MATLAB. It is mentioned that `mpv2 java package` is needed to run these scripts for `sparse approximation`. where can I find this package and how can i install it so that MATLAB can use its method?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it here:
http://www.ux.uis.no/~karlsk/dle/mpv2-class.zip

Extract all files to folder named 'mpv2' (so folder structure is: C:\Some\Folder\mpv2)

```
javaaddpath('C:\Some\Folder\')
```

And to test for success:

```
exist('mpv2.SimpleMatrix') %should return 8 indicating class.
```

Comment: I did it, the result was an error saying `Undefined variable "mpv2" or class "mpv2.SimpleMatrix".` in this line `jD0 = mpv2.SimpleMatrix(D0);`'